# GitLab deployment from marketplace is not linked in helm

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, google-apps-marketplace

Am trying to deploy gitlab from marketplace onto GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). The deployment is successful.

post installation i tried using 'helm list'. However there is no data returned.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the links between helm and marketplace deployment is broken.

So use plain helm install for installing the gitlab.

below is the command i used for installing:

```
helm upgrade --install gitlab gitlab/gitlab --namespace gitlab ^
  --timeout 600 ^
  --set global.hosts.domain=xxxx.com ^
  --set global.hosts.externalIP=xx.xx.xx.xx^
  --set certmanager-issuer.email=xx@xxxx.com ^
  --set global.email.from=xx@xxxx.com ^
  --set global.smtp.address=smtp.xx.xx^
  --set global.smtp.enabled=true ^
  --set global.smtp.port=xxx^
  --set global.smtp.authentication=plain ^
  --set global.smtp.starttls_auto=true ^
  --set global.smtp.user_name=xx@xxxx.com ^
  --set global.smtp.password.key=password ^
  --set global.smtp.password.secret=smtp-secret ^
  --set global.email.reply_to=xx@xxxx.com ^
  --set gitlab-runner.runners.privileged=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow this [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#initialize-helm-and-install-tiller) after installing GitLab from GCP Marketplace.

As suggestion, do make sure you create a new cluster for it, so that the Tiller pod can be scheduled properly.

Keep in mind that you can check if the pods are properly deployed using this command:
kubectl -n kube-system get po

When the Tiller is running, you would need to install Chart, which you can then do an 'helm  list'.